# Replace single backslash from escaped characters

Tags: javascript, regex

How to replace a single backslash in a string? e.g. if you get a string like a windows path then all backslashes are escaping the following character.

```
<macrodef name="resetproperty" >
    <attribute name="name"/>
    <attribute name="value"/>
    <sequential>
        <script language="javascript">
            <![CDATA[
            var path="@{value}";
            path=path.replace(/\\/g, "/");
            project.setProperty('@{name}',path);
            ]]>
        </script>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>;
```

If I perform the replacing on ant side it works with the command

```
 <propertyregex  property="backslash"
                input="${path}"
                global="true"
                regexp="\\"
                replace="/"
    />
```

Comment: This question is confusing.  Given your variable x, what is the desired output?

Comment: I don't think this is valid JS. It should be `var x = "c:\\a\\xy\\bn";`

Comment: @cale_b desired output should be "c:/a/xy/bn"

Comment: @cl3m assume you have an ant file and the value of property contains backslashes which you want to replace. This value could be given as "@{value}" and value is  c:\a\xy\bn

Comment: Can you test your path value before and after the replace? If so, what do you get? The replace itself looks OK to me.

Comment: before I call the macro <resetproperty name="path" value="${path}"/> the echo of  `${path}` is `c:\a\xy\bn` and that string is the value of the attribute "value" in the macro.

Comment: And after? Can you insert alert or console.log statements in the Javascript code to follow the value of "path"?

Comment: `<![CDATA[
                var path="@{value}";
                echo = customcontroller.createTask("echo");
          echo.setMessage(path);
          echo.perform();
                
                ]]>` provides the output from 'c:\a\xy\bn' it looks like `c:ax` in which x stands for some character that looks like a rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript you gave in your question will already replace all backslashes in `path` with forward slashes. For instance, if `@{value}` is `c:\\a\\xy\\bn`, then the final value of `path` will be `"c:/a/xy/bn"`.

Remember that backslash escapes are necessary to represent backslashes in Javascript. If you forget them, your script will not work. In the best case, it will give you an error (if `@{value}` is literally `c:\a\xy\bn` Firefox gives:

```
SyntaxError: malformed hexadecimal character escape sequence
```

But in most cases, Javascript will simply ignore the backslash characters and you will get a totally different result. In Chrome and Firefox, `"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer"` becomes `"C:Program FilesInternet Explorer"`, so that's what you'll get in your `path` variable.

Comment: please see my edits. Its not the point if that string is valid. It comes from a ant resource and I want to customise the variable.

Comment: Wait, now your question seems to contain its own answer. You replace backslashes with the "path.replace" line. What more do you want to know?

Comment: Sorry that my question is still unclear. The point is that the variable or rather attribute "value" has the value `c:\a\xy\bn`.

Comment: If the original value of `path` is `"c:\\a\\xy\\bn"` and you want it to be `"c:/a/xy/bn"`, then the code in your question will do it.

Comment: No it is NOT the orignal value. the original value is like I said `c:\a\xy\bn`.

Comment: `"c:\\a\\xy\\bn"` is the way of saying `c:\a\xy\bn` in Javascript. Try `console.log("c:\\a\\xy\\bn");` and it will print out `c:\a\xy\bn`. So when you say the original value is `c:\a\xy\bn`, do you mean when it's printed out like that to show to humans? Then the Javascript representation is `"c:\\a\\xy\\bn"` and your code will work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106801/discussion-between-nick-s-and-stellamaris).